# div class is active after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My homepage content is into

```
<div class="active">
         Homepage content
       </div>
```

Class active is removed  after some link (link1...link5) is clicked with jquery script

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#link-link1 , #link-link2 , #link-link3 , #link-link4 , #link-link5").click(function(){
   $(".active").css("display","none"); 
})})
```

It work but when i refresh page, class active (homepage content) is visible. I tried this code

```
HTML

<body onLoad="CheckPageLoad();">

    <input type="hidden" name="visit" id="visit" value="" />

</body>

javascript

function CheckPageLoad() {
    if (document.getElementById("visit").value == "") {

        document.getElementById("visit").value = "1";
    }
    else {
               $(".active").css("display","none"); 

    }
}​
```

It is not working. You can try it [here](http://skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/) (and see full code)

Comment: You need to maintain the state of the page in case you are refreshing it for it to retain the disbaled links. you can do that using the local storage or cookies.

Comment: You're not understanding a fundamental property of the web: it's stateless. It has no memory of what you do unless you create the memory by storing data somewhere.

Comment: or you can get this state from your uri hash :)

Comment: simple check `location.hash`

Comment: do you think this? $.fn.urlHash = function()
{
  return window.location.hash.replace('#','');
};
$.urlHash();

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your site, I see a couple things right away. The console showed these 2 errors

```
GET http://skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/Unnamed%20Site%202/demo.css 404 (Not Found) skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/:12
GET http://skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) skusobnastranka1.php5.sk/:20
```

Since your jquery library isn't found, your jquery calls won't execute. Try again after you provide a proper link to a jquery library
e.g. [//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Comment: Hi, if jquery library isnt found it cant work. But my jquery script work. I used other library but this is no problem.

Comment: Then the other comments should be useful for you. You either need to maintain the same page state or store it somewhere.